# What types of mosses are in this flat tray?

Tags: identification, moss

Would anyone be able to identify any on the mosses in this picture?

[image]

I'm trying to make something similar but am having difficulty choosing suitable mosses.

Comment: I just foud a free book "[Moss Grower's Handbook](http://rbg-web2.rbge.org.uk/bbs/Resources/Fletcher.pdf)" which looks like it could have some useful information in it.

Comment: Hi BanksySan. I see you mentioned a book which might help you. If you do find something, feel free to answer your own question so the rest of us can learn. Thanks!

Comment: Alas, no pictures.  Looks like an interesting read nevertheless.

Comment: I just looked at that and it certainly does look interesting. It's very long, though, and if I were you I'd have asked the question here just like you did! Hopefully you'll get some good help. I don't know anything about moss so it will be interesting for me too.

Comment: BanksySan, do you have a list of the mosses you are awaiting in the mail?  I've been learning all about mosses (again, it has been awhile).  Some mosses are tolerant of 'wet feet' or water logging.  Others are not.  It'd be nice to find you've chosen species that need the same type of home.  Have you read this handbook of mosses?  By Fletcher?

Comment: And what were you planning to do for the 'medium'?  pH? Water source?  If your water is too alkaline the moss will die...I am getting 'into' this project, grins.  I know how to do this with sedums but mosses...hummmm.

Comment: @stormy So far I have cushion, carpet and silver moss. Lighting is "whatever", watering could be supplemented with a mist of something delicious to moss.

Comment: @stormy I understand the "getting too into it" feeling.

Comment: Water is delicious to moss/plants.  Don't worry about weird concoctions.  A little fertilizer will be necessary, and little is the operative word.  I am https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiSx8eDsMfQAhVS1WMKHYcMABEQjRwIBw&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mossandstonegardens.com%2Fblog%2F&psig=AFQjCNEF55cOMsNWQD62pB3ahfT-5CXRTQ&ust=1480282345236835 already thinking of projects like this!!

Comment: @stormy That lion is certainly eye catching!

Comment: Isn't he wonderful.  I've seen this done with lawn grasses as well, in far more light of course.  They spray the grass seed on in a mixture that holds the seed to any surface, includes fertilizer and a mulch like stuff that  holds the moisture longer.  Go look up mosses, and then you'll find to the right? Pictures and MORE.  Yummm.

Comment: On identification questions, please ask about one species at a time. Pictures from multiple angles, including a closeup shot, will make identification far more accurate.

Comment: @J.Musser In this case that would have been very difficult as this is the only photo I have of these mosses.  Given that I don't know what they are, finding photos of them isolated would have been a bit of an excersize in futility.

Comment: I understand, @BanksySan. I'm explaining a little about why you didn't get a good answer, and our site expectations on questions tagged 'identification'. In this case since that isn't your moss I see why you can't conform to that

Answer (score 2):

This is an interesting question.  Identification takes a BIT more information than any picture could tell. Without a microscope, specimens and library it is ALWAYS A GUESS.  You are standing upon MORE than mosses, lichens for sure.  Moss or moss like plants are a joy to step upon, intermittently stepped upon or else they turn into mush.  These soft mounded plants conjure up ancient aquifers, maidenhair fern, moist air and warmth. Think about that. What does that mean? Where do you live?  Is this outdoors or indoors is this sample from an outdoor environment or a greenhouse?  There is no way you could pick one of these 'examples' of soft fuzzy 'plants' and grow it just anywhere.  This is the beauty of being able to grow plants.  We learn about an alternate universe right next to ours we sorta kinda understand and one that our very lives depend.

This sounds like a wonderful project.  Are you to make this moss stuff into a floor?  How about a vertical wall hanging? What are the parameters for this project?

Comment: This is my first attempt, totally new, no idea what I'm doing, project.  It'll be a bath mat though.  Moisture supplied by the mist in the bathroom and watch dripping from people who use it.  So far I have gone with a mixture of cushion moss, carpet moss and silver moss.  Haven't arrived yet though.

Comment: How about light?  If you want to keep the moisture in the bathroom you need to remember to not turn on the bathroom ventilation fan.  Lighting will be interesting.  The bathroom light will not be enough.  The light should be placed at least a foot above the mosses depending on what you are using for lights.  If too warm then you have to raise it up.  You also need drainage so that there won't be the problem of any water sitting at the base of those plants.  Don't think just the bathroom mist will be enough.  Huummm.  How often will people take a shower/bath?  I gotta go think about this.

Comment: I am thinking that your moss should have another display where you are able to care for your mat and put it down by the tub when necessary.  Sure is a pretty thing.  Moss does well in shade OUTDOORS.  The full spectrum light is necessary for photosynthesis...what light were you planning to use?  What wattage?

Comment: Do you have a list of the scientific or botanical names?  Can't use the common names.

Comment: alas, no. When they arrive I'll post some photos though, if that'll help.

Comment: Nope, photos aren't that helpful with mosses.  The people you are purchasing your mosses from HAVE TO KNOW.  Can you call them?  Otherwise, this will be a great learning experience for you...but only if you know the true names.  Common names are worthless, seriously.  If you could take microscopic or at least 10X magnification pictures, sure we could make an ID.  Give me their name and I'll talk to them if you want...grins.  What a cool gift to make for family, friends!  Even miniature flats!  'Close your eyes and walk in a tropical forest or walk on a sand beach using sand as a base'??

Comment: You have my word that will ask and report back.

Comment: Would sand work as a base?  I hadn't considered it.

Comment: Well, yes...but I'm looking at a mixture of soil and peat moss as better, need the acidity.  I'm still bumping around the internet on this stuff.  Those people you bought your moss from should have instructions!!  Of some sort to include the real names of your purchases!  I am thinking you want this to last longer than a week or two, yes?  Moss indoors is different than moss out doors.  Not an easy plant to grow unless it finds the perfect conditions out of doors.  Have you run across that in your research?

Comment: I have read that there are some distinct requirements for some.  Mostly though, I was lead to believe that they were pretty hardy.

Comment: No way are mosses hardy.  Shame on them.  They do well in the wild but to know how to artificially grow them they are on the top of the list of MOST DIFFICULT.  When YOU have to provide the correct environment, chemicals, humidity, lighting, amount of moisture in the soil, heck, the soil or medium YOU have to provide...oh my goodness.  But on the positive side, you get your mosses growing and keep them for at least a half year, you will know more than most about plants.  You have to, grins!  And what a super conversation piece!!  This is so similar to growing Bonsai!!